# Get the new link of a live streaming in YouTube

Tags: youtube, live, smart-tv

I have a YouTube channel which change its live link whenever init a new trasmission. Im using this link to get it updated https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCpOz3CN6mDlxkE7-m5AS1aQ/live but I can't use it with siptv app in my smart tv. Only recognizes a vídeo link. Somebody knows how I can solve it?